# Is there any characterization of a group $G$ with subgroup $N \lhd G$ such that $G/N \cong N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. What do we know about the structure of $G$ if $G/N \cong N$?

I know that some possibilities are that $G \cong N \times N$ or that $G \cong C_{|N|^2}$, but I don't know if that is an exhaustive list.

Comment: A more traditional question would be to ask, given $N$, what are the groups $G$ with $G/N \approx N$. Such groups $G$ are called extensions of $N$ by $N$. The collection of such groups $G$ is itself a group. Google this: group extension.

Comment: Note that $C_{|N|^2}$ only works if $N$ is cyclic.

Comment: This is probably too broad. For example, when $N$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group, there are way too many possibilities for $G$ to classify.

Comment: I think so too now after looking at group extensions. My naive self thought that semidirect products were the only way to construct groups out of smaller groups, but little did I know that was only the tip of the iceberg.